# How do I forward declare a boost::spirit rule?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Here's a very simple `boost::spirit` example demonstrating an issue I'm running into - when I compile it, I get `'parsers::parseTest': redefinition; multiple initialization` - how do I forward declare a rule? Using `2.5.2` if it matters.

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/adt/adapt_adt.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_object.hpp>
#include <string>

struct test
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(test, a,b)


namespace parsers
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator it;
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
    const rule<it, test()> parseTest;
}

namespace parsers
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator it;
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
    const rule<it, test()> parseTest = int_ >> ',' >> int_;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant declaration `const rule<it, test()> parseTest;` is also its definition, which, in this code, uses the default constructor to initialize it. Just omit that line.

Alternatively, if you want to provide `parseTest` definition with the initializer in another source file, you must declare that `const` as `extern` because `const` at global and namespace scope implies internal linkage (`static`).

```
// .h
namespace parsers {
    extern const rule<it, test()> parseTest;
}

// .cc
const rule<it, test()> parsers::parseTest = int_ >> ',' >> int_;
```